# Meteor, coffeescript files running on every page

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I am just getting started with Meteor and have encountered something that isn't necessarily an issue but something that I just don't understand. I have the following code in a file called `chat.coffee`...

```
Meteor.setInterval ( ->
  console.log "Hello " + roomName
  Meteor.call('keepAlive', Meteor.user(), roomName)
  return
), 5000
```

I originally was under the impression that coffee-script files only ran on their associated html files. This doesn't seem to be the case here as this code runs on every single page regardless of the file name. Is this the intended way things are supposed to work, and if so, is there a way to enforce that only certain code runs on certain pages.

One thing to mention is that this code is running in the client side folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client side, Meteor will associate your templates with their javascript functions and helpers based upon shared *template names*, but that is not inherently tied to your *file names*.

By way of example, if you have a template named "chat" in an html file as follows:

```
<template name="chat"></template>
```

Meteor will run scripts such as `Template.chat.helpers({})` or `Template.chat.events({})` only in connection with the "chat" template.  But that is not dependent on your file naming conventions.  It could be placed in a file name chat.js for organization and convention, but could equally well reside in a file named client.js or any other arbitrarily named .js file.

Similarly, your `<template name="chat">` could reside in a file named chat.html, or client.html, or an arbitrary name of your choosing.

Your setInterval function is not tied to a specific template so it will run on every page, even if it resides in a file named chat.js.

Answer (score 2):

Correct.

Meteor merges all your javascript ( via coffeescript ) and all the html, which it stores in its own special way.   It merges all the html in heads and body etc into a page and serves that up,  and it will then render templates as you specify.

To have a more "page" oriented app you can use something like iron router.